# How to understand if wrong input is given using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on Selenium. I am working on captcha. I am manually putting the captchas. The code should be like this that the captcha input is given manually, then the Enter button is automatically pressed. If the captcha is correct then bingo! We are in next page and the work is done/ However if it is wrong (in which case after Enter is pressed, there should be a warning 'captcha is wrong' or something like that) then driver.refresh() is used to refresh the page. And we start with the 1st step of putting the new captcha manually.
However, I am not sure how to use python to 'look' if the captcha is wrong. In that case a if statement will be used to refresh the page.
I was trying something like this after getting the id of the captcha wrong message:

```
z = browser.find_element_by_name("blabla") 
if z== True:
    browser.refresh()
```

But it didnt work.

Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Observe the difference between:**

```
s = input("Type something: ")

if s == True:
    print("You typed something!")
else:
    print("You didn't type anything!")

s = input("Type something: ")
```

Input:

```
Type something: Hello World!
```

Output:

```
You didn't type anything!
```

**And:**

```
if s:
    print("You typed something!")
else:
    print("You didn't type anything!")
```

Input:

```
Type something: Hello World!
```

Output:

```
You typed something!
```

---

As you can see, even if a string is not empty, like `'hi'`, calling `'hi' == True` will return `False`.